# Moving tableview on xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have read how to move an object on xcode4.2 and I did successfully moving a button. But I cant move a tableview.

Here are codes on Viewcontroller.m:

```
- (IBAction) unhide {
if (flag==1) {
    flag=0;

    CGRect frame = testtable.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x; // new x coordinate
    frame.origin.y = 150; // new y coordinate



    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.25];
    testtable.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
else{
    flag=1;

    CGRect frame = testtable.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x; // new x coordinate
    frame.origin.y = 350; // new y coordinate



    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.25];
    testtable.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: testtable is probably `nil`.  P.S. This animation style is very old, you should use the new block based one that came with iOS 4

Comment: what exactly isn't working? is your unhide method being called? is testtable actually nil?

Comment: @borrrden How can I fix it? Sorry for my stupid question, I'm totally newbie on objective c. I'm happy if you give me tutorials about "block based one". Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Shaun Yes testtable is nil. When I click unhide button, tableview didn't move to new place.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available for the new block based methods.  The more important thing is to make sure `testtable` is actually valid (i.e. not `nil`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple, Don't forget to create outlet for table view.
For example if your outlet name is testTable, then try this code block:

```
if(flag==0)
{
    flag=1;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^()
     {
         testTable.frame=CGRectMake(0, 150, testTable.frame.size.width, testTable.frame.size.height);
     }];
}
else
{
    flag=0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^()
     {
         testTable.frame=CGRectMake(0, 350, testTable.frame.size.width, testTable.frame.size.height);
     }];
}
```

Hope this will help you. Good luck